# Route WCF ServiceHost to another computer

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

GoodDay,

I'm not a guru when it comes to WCF, but i do know the basics.

My question is, how do i create a ServiceHost on machine X, while the code is on machine Y?

if i build and run this code on my dev machine(localhost) :

```
servicehost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService1));
servicehost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService1), new NetTcpBinding(),"net.tcp://my.datacenter.com/MyApp/MyService1"); //This is normally set to localhost.
```

What implementation must be done on the datacenter server, so that if i had to point to http://my.datacenter.com/MyApp/MyService1 , it will route the service operation to my dev machine (localhost).

However, the datacenter should not be accessible via the internet.

It is a possible infrastructure that we researching to see if we can create a service bus type architecture so that all our customers can invoke other customer services running on their respective machines just by calling our datacenter url.

We have looked at Windows Azure, but we have our own datacenter infrasture that we wish to leverage off. Come think of it, we kind of building our own Azure, on a very very basic scale.

How does one go creating this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just to check. Does your issue just request redirection ? It was not clear not me.

Comment: well not only redirection only. 

For example, If CustomerA hosts a calculator services on http://cal.custa.datacenter.com, 

Before CustomerB can access this service, we need to check that he has the correct license and authentication to do so.

so the datacenter will also need intervene of the redirection

Answer (score 3):

WCF in .NET 4 has a new feature called the routing service which does some of that - the clients will connect and send their messages to machine A, while that machine basically just re-routes the request to machine B.

Check out these resources (or find a lot more by googling or binging for "WCF 4 Routing service"):

- [10-4 Episode 40: the new WCF Routing Service (video)](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/10-4/10-4-Episode-40-The-New-WCF-Routing-Service/)
- [WCF 4 Routing Service Multicast sample](http://dannycohen.info/2010/03/02/wcf-4-routing-service-multicast-sample/)
- [WCF Routing Service and custom filters](http://blogs.profitbase.com/tsenn/?p=23)
- [Creating Routing Service using WCF 4.0, .NET Framework 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=470)
- [Content-based routing with WCF 4](http://blogs.u2u.be/peter/post/2009/10/07/Content-based-routing-with-WCF-4.aspx)
- [WebServices and Routing in WCF 4](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcfprerelease/thread/72fad31b-3c1d-4300-9081-d70af383f705)